# How to get access to file to delete for emulators files?

Tags: c#, file, directory, delete-file

I'm facing issue to remove full directory because some file get this error `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'pstore.bin' is denied.'`

I've tried to give permission to single File but same, tested this but doesn't work too:

```cs
var di = new DirectoryInfo(item);
di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Normal;
Directory.Delete(item, true);
```

Not sure how I can remove this file, I've tested almost everything I found on this forum, and not sure what is wrong. To be clear this file is from Android Studio AVD Emulator.

Updating exception notes:

```
**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'pstore.bin' is denied.'**
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    TwitterSuite_v._1._0.Form1.fullZipAll.AnonymousMethod__0(string) in Form1.cs
    [External Code]
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the C# application run with *administrator privileges*, add a manifest file (`*.manifest`) to the application. To create manifest file, follow this path in Visual Studio IDE:

- `Project > Add New Item > Application Manifest File`

For the application to run with administrative privileges, you need to add the element `<requestedExecutionLevel>` in the `app.manifest` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

                <!-- In order for the program to run with administrator privileges, you need to add the following line to the *.manifest file. -->
                <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>

    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application></application>
    </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

If this solution doesn't work for you, get the error code in the thrown exception and update the question:

```cs
try
{
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(item);
    di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Normal;
    Directory.Delete(item, true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Try to verify for what reason this error is occurring:

- The file can be *read-only*. [UnauthorizedAccessException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.unauthorizedaccessexception?view=net-6.0)
- There may be a file that does *I/O operation* during deletion. [IOException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ioexception?view=net-6.0)
- The caller does not have the required permission. [SecurityException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securityexception?view=net-6.0)
- The directory described by this `DirectoryInfo` object doesn't exist or could not be found. [DirectoryNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directorynotfoundexception?view=net-6.0)

###### References

- [Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "..." is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534782/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-denied/40475532)
- [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)
- [How do I create/edit a Manifest file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050478/how-do-i-create-edit-a-manifest-file)

Comment: thanks gonna test it, the message is same as in thread

Comment: Didnt help me sadly. You can check updated post exception.

Comment: Run Android Studio and Visual Studio IDE with administrator rights. The current user must have "full control" right on the `pstore.bin` file.

Comment: but I create amulator via avdmanager, and start them via commands. So if start only visual studio via administrator rights? this should helps?